# Nextcord python бот для дискорд отвечает только в личные сообщения

Tags: python, discord, бот

Я недавно создал бота для дискорд но при вызове команды на сервере он ничего не отвечает, а если пишешь ему в личные сообщения все работает

````
from nextcord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
@bot.command(name="hi")
async def hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send('hello')

bot.run(TOKEN)```
````

Comment: так же я проверил и бот может писать сообщения в чатах. Но команда все равно не работает

Answer (score 0):

У тебя скорее всего в `commands.Bot(intents = discord.Intents.default())` по этому он видит только сообщения от пользователей, чтобы это исправить, замени `default()` на `all()` чтобы вышло
`commands.Bot(intents = discord.Intents.all())`
И тогда все заработает)